# SSR Angular 8 application have lazy-load modules as undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, lazy-loading, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to set up my Angular 8 application to run with SSR but my lazyloaded modules triggers some undefined errors in webpack when I run my application with `ng serve`.
It was working fine before with Angular 7 but going to Angular 8 broke everything.
this is the error I'm getting on runtime (in node console)

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/gwenaellarmet/Documents/Projects/ng-nouma/dist/server.js:137403:30)
    at Function.requireEnsure [as e] (/Users/gwenaellarmet/Documents/Projects/ng-nouma/dist/server.js:137422:25)
    at ɵ11 (/Users/gwenaellarmet/Documents/Projects/ng-nouma/dist/server.js:139660:6210)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (/Users/gwenaellarmet/Documents/Projects/ng-nouma/dist/server.js:232758:39)
```

I tried changing some of the tsconfig and the angular.json config but I'm always getting the same error.
Ivy is not enable as it also triggers some error on build; I think it's linked but I'm not sure so for now I'm trying to get it work without Ivy

```
ERROR in src/app/pages/search/search.module.ts(68,12): error TS-991010: Value at position 12 in the NgModule.importss of SearchModule is not a reference: [object Object]
src/app/app.module.ts(41,12): error TS-991010: Value at position 6 in the NgModule.importss of AppModule is not a reference: [object Object]
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "allowEmptyCodegenFiles": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "paths": {
      "@nouma/core": ["app/core/core.index.ts"],
      "@nouma/coreModule": ["app/core/core.module.ts"],
      "@nouma/material": ["app/utils/nouma-material/nouma-material.module.ts"],
      "@nouma/ui": ["app/ui/ui.index.ts"],
      "@nouma/env": ["environments/environment.ts"],
      "@nouma/errors": ["app/pages/error-pages/error-pages.index.ts"],
      "@nouma/home": ["app/pages/home/home.component.ts"],
      "@nouma/popins": ["app/pages/popins/popins.index.ts"],
      "@nouma/popinsModule": ["app/pages/popins/popins.module.ts"]
    },
    "incremental": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app-server",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ng-nouma": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/app/utils/nouma-material/nouma-app-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js"
            ],
            "lazyModules": [
              "src/app/pages/search/search.module",
              "src/app/pages/search/search.module",
              "src/app/pages/tender-detail/tender-detail.module",
              "src/app/pages/sources/sources.module",
              "src/app/pages/offer/offer.module",
              "src/app/pages/forgotten/forgotten.module",
              "src/app/pages/confirm/confirm.module",
              "src/app/pages/alerts/alerts.module",
              "src/app/pages/bookmarks/bookmarks.module",
              "src/app/pages/account/account.module",
              "src/app/pages/home/home.module"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng-nouma:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ng-nouma:build:production"
            },
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "ng-nouma:build:local"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ng-nouma:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ng-nouma-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ng-nouma:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ng-nouma:serve:production"
            },
            "local": {
              "devServerTarget": "ng-nouma:serve:local"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ng-nouma",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

packages.json

```
{
  "name": "ng-nouma",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "ivy-ngcc",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:opti": "ng serve --aot --optimization",
    "start:local": "ng serve --configuration=local",
    "start:prod": "ng serve --configuration=production",
    "build": "ng build --aot --build-optimizer --optimization",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --optimization",
    "build:local": "ng build --configuration=local --aot --build-optimizer --optimization",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "bundle-report": "ng build --stats-json --aot --build-optimizer --optimization && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/browser/stats.json",
    "bundle-report:prod": "ng build --stats-json --prod --aot --build-optimizer --optimization && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/browser/stats.json",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:ssr:staging": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles:staging && npm run compile:server",
    "build:ssr:local": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles:local && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --optimization && ng run ng-nouma:server:production",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles:staging": "ng build --aot --build-optimizer --optimization && ng run ng-nouma:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles:local": "ng build --aot --build-optimizer --optimization --configuration=local && ng run ng-nouma:server"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.18",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@nguniversal/common": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "angular2-toaster": "^7.0.0",
    "angulartics2": "^7.5.2",
    "core-js": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "foundation-sites": "6.5.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng-intercom": "^8.0.0-beta.1",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-foundation": "1.0.8",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.1.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^7.9.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "terser": "^4.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

I'm building my application with `npm run build:ssr` and serving it with `npm run serve:ssr`

I need my application rendering all the modules and markup with SSR for SEO purposes and would love to have some help to where the issue is.

Comment: Did you migrate all of your loadChildren routes for Angular 8?

Comment: Yes, this all my routes look like this now, following the Angular 8 syntax :
`{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  }`

Comment: Drop all the modules and then include one by one until you find the offender.

Comment: Good Idea, I'm going to give that a try

Comment: This error is in the `server.js` file. If I remember correctly, this file is not part of the Angular bundles. Those are loaded separately. So I'm wondering if the server is failing to bootstrap the app module at the beginning. I would be tempted to run the SSR in a debugger.

Comment: Without any lazyloaded module, everything works fine, so the issue is here as I expected, I'll try to debug the SSR to find where exactly the issue is

Comment: "Ivy will not be ready for all use cases. Some features such as i18n or Angular Universal will likely not have full compatibility yet in the preview." https://blog.angular.io/a-plan-for-version-8-0-and-ivy-b3318dfc19f7

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that there are two copies of Angular in the older way of setting up Universal and it confuses the lazy loading system.

You can manually fix this issue by updating the following:

**package.json**

> add `--bundleDependencies all` at the end of the value of
>   `build:client-and-server-bundles`

**server.ts**

> remove the following lines
>
> ```
> import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';     
> import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';  
> import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
> enableProdMode();
> const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');
> ```
>
> then add
>
> ```
> const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');
> ```

**main.server.ts**

> add
>
> ```
> export {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
> export {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
> ```

**webpack.server.config.js**

> add
>
> ```
> externals: {
>  './dist/server/main': 'require("./server/main")'
> }
> ```

Reference: [fix lazy loading and bundleDependencies](https://github.com/vikerman/v8-lazy/commit/515239be1b233946e4a1d15a8712a0bc9f5490cc)

Comment: This response fixed my issue, this was indeed the problem, the Universal team is working on the release for Angular 8.
I don't understand why this response was downvote. Thanks a lot @paulws

Comment: For this am getting the error of   " Error: Cannot find module 'require("./server/main")'  "   after final build.

Comment: This answer worked for me, with the exception of the last part. I had to remove the 



externals: {
 './dist/server/main': 'require("./server/main")'
}

Thank you

Comment: `@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader` is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue, this one as well: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1195. What worked for me was to apply the fix (https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/v8-upgrade-guide.md), but to not include the `--bundleDependencies all` flag.

Here's a basic working example using gCloud for SSR:
https://github.com/jrodl3r/ng-fire-universal

Answer (score -1):

Long story short - I have just removed `enableProdMode();` from server.ts and it starts working.

---

It was here by angular 7 but angular 8 needs code changes in server.ts file, so

- I made server.bak.ts as a backup file,
- set new blank project with SSR and
- got code from it to server.ts file.